# Logic issue with session storage - Remember class on refresh - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to jquery and asked a similar question recently but am struggling with the final logic here.

So I've got this script that whenever a div is scrolled in to the viewport it adds a class of `.prod__viewed` and then I have a counter that shows how many are viewed and the total number of divs, so I want to be able to remember the all the divs that have `.prod__viewed` on reload of the page using sessions storage, but it is currently adding the class to every div and I can't figure out why.

```
$.fn.prodInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};


$(window).on('resize load scroll', function() {
    $('.prod__item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prodInViewport()) {
        $(this).addClass('prod__viewed');
        sessionStorage.setItem('viewed', 'prod__viewed');
    } 
    });

  var numItems = $('.prod__item').length;
  var totalNumItems = $('.prod__viewed').length;
  var prodCountCheck = $('.prod__count__container');
  var positionY = $(this).scrollTop();
  var pageHeight = $(this).height();
  var scrollHeight = $('body').height();
  var scrollPercent = (positionY / (scrollHeight - pageHeight)) * 100;
  var prodCountElement = $('.prod__count__container').outerHeight();

  if (prodCountCheck.length == 1) {
    $('.prod__count__content')
      .html('<span>You&#39;ve seen <strong>' + totalNumItems + '</strong> of <strong>' + numItems + '</strong> prods</span>');

    $('.prod__load__bar').css({
      'top': prodCountElement,
      'width': scrollPercent + "%"
    });
  }
});



if (sessionStorage.getItem("viewed")) {
    $(".prod__item").addClass(sessionStorage.getItem("viewed"));
}
```

```
<section class="prod__count__wrapper">
    <div class="prod__count__container">
        <div class="prod__count__content"></div><!-- /.prod__count__content -->
    </div><!-- /.prod__count__container -->

    <div class="prod__load__bar"></div><!-- /.prod__load__bar -->
</section><!-- /.prod__count__wrapper -->


<section class="prod__wrapper">
    <div class="prod__container">
        <div class="prod__item">
            <div class="prod__item--img">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
            </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

            <div class="prod__item--deets">
                <div class="prod__name">
                    My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
                </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

                <div class="prod__price">
                    £14.99
                </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
            </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
        </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

        <div class="prod__item">
            <div class="prod__item--img">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
            </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

            <div class="prod__item--deets">
                <div class="prod__name">
                    My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
                </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

                <div class="prod__price">
                    £14.99
                </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
            </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
        </div><!-- /.prod__item -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Any advice about where I am going wrong would be awesome as this is tricky stuff haha

CodePen: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/vYYoVZ

Comment: Is this statement correct: `return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;`? Doesn't that always return `false`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jQuery addClass function the wrong way. The syntax for jQuery addClass is as follows:

```
$('selector').addClass('classname');
```

Which can be found here https://api.jquery.com/addClass/.
The reason it's assigning the prod__viewed to all classes is because your selector is "All elements with the class prod__item (.prod__item)".

I think what you try to achieve is something like:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("viewed")) {
    $(sessionStorage.getItem("viewed")).addClass("prod__viewed");
}
```

Alright, I assume your page is static. But even if it isn't you can still make it work. You want to save products to session storage if they're viewed. You can't save the entire `DOM element` to the session storage so you need something to identify the products. I'm assuming every product has a unique `ID` so let's use that. When you view a product you save it to the sessionStorage. You can do that like so:

```
// At the start you create an object in sessionStorage. 
sessionStorage.setItem('viewed', JSON.stringify([]))

// To add an item we use the ID and save it to the sessionStorage. We can do it like so:
viewed = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('viewed'));
viewed.push(ID) // ID of Product That Has Been Viewed
sessionStorage.setItem('viewed', viewed)
```

Now at the start of the page you can read it like so:

```
viewed = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('viewed'));
for (ID in viewed) {
    $('selectorThatFindsProductOnID').addClass('prod__viewed');
}
```

Comment: Cheers, yeah it doesn't fix my issue but is a valid suggestion.

Comment: The other reason is because you assign the product elements to the same key in the SessionStorage it looks like. (`sessionStorage.setItem('viewed', 'prod__viewed');`) which constantly overrides the older elements.

Comment: Yeah basically as I scroll and elements get given the .prod__viewed class I want this remembered if they reload the page basically but I am a complete noob to session storage.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look and feel free to ask about it if anything is unclear

Comment: Hey, some time has passed, have you been able to get it working?